# setting paytm callback url to localhost

Tags: scala, spring-boot, payment-gateway

i want to set paytm callback url to localhost like this:

```
''''val checkSumServiceHelper: CheckSumServiceHelper = com.paytm.pg.merchant.CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper
val parameters: util.TreeMap[String, String] = new util.TreeMap[String, String]
val merchantKey: String = "demo_merchantKey"
parameters.put("MID", "my MID")
parameters.put("ORDER_ID", "nnnnnnnnn")
parameters.put("CUST_ID", "CUST001")
parameters.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1")
parameters.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WEB")
parameters.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "my INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID")
parameters.put("WEBSITE", "my_WEBSITE")
parameters.put("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost:7171/callback")

val checksum = checkSumServiceHelper.genrateCheckSumGAE(merchantKey, parameters)
'''
```

but its not working for me

Comment: did you set callback url? i have same issue

Comment: my nodejs app is running on port 4000 so i create callback url `http://localhost:4000/callback`

Answer (score 1):

my nodejs app is running on port 4000 so i create callback url

`http://localhost:4000/callback`

this may help you.